# Как оптимальнее формировать коллекции товаров?

Tags: mysql, интернет-магазин

В карточке товара выводится список ссылок на товары одного фасона, но разных цветов, пример на скрине:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Изначально список формировался запросом на одинаковые артикулы. Решил ввести принудительное назначение в коллекции, чтобы исключить ошибки в написании артикула.
Добавил две таблицы, см.скрин.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как создаю новую коллекцию:

1. добавляю строку в таблице collections, из этой таблицы использую уникальный id.
2. добавляю необходимые товары в таблицу collection_items - одна строка - один товар, объединяя их значением collection_id (id из пункта 1).
   Получаю такую коллекцию, а всего таких коллекций будет примерно 3-6 млн при 12 млн товаров.
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Смущает таблица collections - в ней по большому счету используется только одна автоинкрементная колонка.
Как обойтись без этой таблицы? Использовать UID? UID формирует цифробуквенную строку, хотелось бы обойтись исключительно полями INT. Или вообще вся задумка неверная?

Comment: *Как обойтись без этой таблицы?* Ну вообще-то никак (альтернативы типа CSV или JSON-списка продуктов - это прямой путь на поле с граблями). Другой вопрос - за каким хреном этой таблице синтетический ПК? его роль прекрасно исполнит составной ключ по полям идентификаторов коллекции и продукта. Да и великая необходимость в поле ord тоже под большим вопросом...

Comment: Вы про какую таблицу и про какой ПК? Я имел ввиду таблицу collections - как обойтись без неё. Поле ord - для отображения списка с подробными товарами в нужной последовательности.

Comment: *Вы про какую таблицу и про какой ПК?* Про таблицу `collection_items` и поле `id`. *Я имел ввиду таблицу collections - как обойтись без неё.* С ней генерация идентификатора для новой коллекции упрощается. Всё равно я так понимаю, что в запросах на получение информации она участвовать не будет, ибо никаких смысловых полей в ней не наблюдается.

Comment: Так точно,таблица collections в запросах не будет участвовать. А по поводу необходимости collection_items.id - Вы имеете ввиду то, что это индекс, который не будет использоваться?

Comment: *А по поводу необходимости collection_items.id - Вы имеете ввиду то, что это индекс, который не будет использоваться?* При чём тут индекс? `id` - это, как я понимаю, полноценное поле, к тому же автоинкрементное и первичный индекс. Если так, и если объекты в `collection_items` не составляют самостоятельную сущность, то это поле явно лишнее.

Comment: В таблице collection_items требуется уникальность связок , я добавил ограничение ALTER TABLE `collection_items` ADD UNIQUE `collection_items_unique`(`collection_id`, `product_id`). Но еще нужна будет скорость, строк будет уже минимум 12млн, т.е. по сути почти на каждый товар будет создана строка, кроме товаров без коллекции. А выборка по этой таблице будет скорее всего как два join на саму себя. Поэтому я думаю, что id пригодится. Попробую сгенерировать эти миллионы и протестировать без id и с id. И сейчас только дошло,что нужна уникальность еще и по product_id - товар только в одной коллекции

Comment: *Поэтому я думаю, что id пригодится.* Интересно, как... *нужна уникальность еще и по product_id - товар только в одной коллекции* Тогда этот геморрой вообще ни о чём - выбросить всё нафиг, и добавить поле коллекции в таблицу товаров.

Comment: И правда, я достоин награды Переоптимизатор 2020 года... Но запрос сложнее будет и скорее всего придется отдельно выносить получение товаров из коллекции. Попробовал в одном запросе сделать, где получаю текущий товар, приджойнив таблицу товаров на саму себя, получил в explain полмиллиона строк. А еще надо для каждого товара из коллекции получить картинки, которые в своей таблице...

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112468/discussion-between---and-akina).